# Get postValue from finished ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asihttprequest

I'd like to know how to retrieve a post value from a finished ASIHTTPRequest.

When I perform the request I do this:

```
[request setPostValue:uniqueID forKey:@"bookUniqueId"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tempDir]) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:tempDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}
[fileManager release];

tempDir = [[tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:uniqueID]stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:tempDir];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

because I want to download the zip file, named like the ID of my book.

In the `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request` method I need that ID to unzip the file. I can't save the ID in an ivar because I want to support multiple asynchronous downloads.

How can I do this? Is there something similar to the inexistent method `[request postValueForKey: key]` ?

Comment: Be aware the ASIHTTPRequest library has been deprecated. I would not recommend it for a new project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenver you create your `ASIFormDataRequest` Just set its **userinfo** and get it like this.

For setting user Info use this.

```
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YOUR_VALUE" forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"]];
```

For getting user Info use this.

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
     NSDictionary *dict = [request userInfo];
     NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `userInfo` property of `ASIHTTPRequest`

Like the following

```
request.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[request.userInfo setValue:yourID forKey:@"your id"];
```

And then in `requestFinished`

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    yourid = [request userInfo] valueForKey:@"your id"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take the Marvin answer only because he has been the first to answer..